# SQL Pivot to Return more than 1 value

Tags: pivot

Here's the issue.  I have 2 tables that I am currently using in a pivot to return a single value, MAX(Date).  I have been asked to return additional values associated with that particular MAX(Date).  I know I can do this with an OVER PARTITION but it would require me doing about 8 or 9 LEFT JOINS to get the desired output.  I was hoping there is a way to get my existing PIVOT to return these values.  More specifically, let's say each MAX(Date) has a data source and we want that particular source to become part of the output.  Here is a simple sample of what I am talking about:

```
    Create table #Email
    (
        pk_id int not null identity primary key,
        email_address varchar(50),
        optin_flag bit default(0),
        unsub_flag bit default(0)
    )

Create table #History
    (
        pk_id int not null identity primary key,
        email_id int not null,
        Status_Cd char(2),
        Status_Ds varchar(20),
        Source_Cd char(3),
        Source_Desc varchar(20),
        Source_Dttm datetime
    )

Insert into #Email
Values
    ('test@test.com',1,0),
    ('blank@blank.com',1,1)

Insert into #History
values
    (1,'OP','OPT-IN','WB','WEB','1/2/2015 09:32:00'),
    (1,'OP','OPT-IN','WB','WEB','1/3/2015 10:15:00'),
    (1,'OP','OPT-IN','WB','WEB','1/4/2015 8:02:00'),
    (2,'OP','OPT-IN','WB','WEB','2/1/2015 07:22:00'),
    (2,'US','UNSUBSCRIBE','EM','EMAIL','3/2/2015 09:32:00'),
    (2,'US','UNSUBSCRIBE','ESP','SERVICE PROVIDER','3/2/2015 09:55:00'),
    (2,'US','UNSUBSCRIBE','WB','WEB','3/2/2015 10:15:00')

;with dates as 
    (
    select 
        email_id,
        [OP] as [OptIn_Dttm],
        [US] as [Unsub_Dttm]
    from 
        (
        select
            email_id,
            status_cd,
            source_dttm
        from #history
        ) as src
    pivot (min(source_dttm) for status_cd in ([OP],[US])) as piv
    )

select
    e.pk_id as email_id,
    e.email_address,
    e.optin_flag,
    /*WANT TO GET THE OPTIN SOURCE HERE*/ /*<-------------*/
    d.OptIn_Dttm,
    e.unsub_flag,
    d.Unsub_Dttm
    /*WANT TO GET THE UNSUB SOURCE HERE*/ /*<-------------*/
from #Email e
    left join dates d on e.pk_id = d.email_id
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want for the final result, can you take that sample data and show the final result in a table?

Comment: I want the final output to produce the columns:
Email_id, Email_Address, Optin_Flag, Optin_Dttm, Source_Cd <the Optin Source_Cd>, Source_Desc <the Optin Source_Desc>, Unsub_Flag,
Unsub_Dttm,Source_Cd <the Unsub Source_Cd>, 
Source_Desc <the Unsub Source_Desc>